# Classic ASP application Memory Leak: Issue in setting up Windbg

Tags: asp-classic, iis-6, windbg

I have a classic asp application deployed on IIS 6.0. The application crashes after every 1 or 2 hours.

To test for memory leaks, I installed Windbg 6. To monitor the process following steps are executed:

1. Execute command: gflags.exe /i w3wp.exe +ust
2. Recycle application pool
3. Attach Windbg to corresponding w3wp process.

Once the process is attached, the application is not accessible. The browser just waits forever. If I exit from Windbg, the application starts working perfectly alright.

I tried searching but of no help.

Comment: are you allowing your app to continue running??? enter `g` at the WinDbg command prompt and hit enter or hit F5

Answer (score 0):

Why are you attaching WinDBG?  Why not attach DebugDiag to the process -- configure it to track the w3wp, and to generate a memory dump if memory goes over a certain limit OR if the process crashes.  Lots of guides out there available, but usually you introduce WinDBG only *after* you have your memory dump -- and you analyze the dump with it.